# string /UTF8 problem

Tags: objective-c

i am having some simple problem in objective c maybe you can help .

i have 2 strings that get their value like that :

```
triger = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%f", x],
                                          [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%f", y],
                                          nil];

X = [triger objectAtIndex:0]; // coordinates
Y = [triger objectAtIndex:1];

NSLog(@"%@", Y);
NSLog(@"%@", X);

if (Y == @"0" && X == @"0") // TOUCH TRIGER
```

now the NSLog is show me the value y=0 and x=1, **AND THE IF STATEMENT IS ALWAYS DONE..** 
why is that ?? what am i doing wrong ?

thanks  . . . . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to change your if statement to this:

```
if([Y isEqualToString:@"0"] && [X isEqualToString:@"0"])
```

Comment: THANKS a lot ! why cant i do it in my way? and if i want to check if not equal, what is the way ??

Comment: You can't check it your way because NSStrings are objects.

isEqualToString is a method that returns a boolean value. So if you want to check not equal to you can do this: ![Y isEqualToString:@"0"]

Comment: To clarify what joel said with you way you are just testing if the two objects are the same instance, (the same location in memory) whereas isEqualToString: test the content of the two strings to see if they are equivalent.